# What is the solution of differential equation : $x(y^3-x)dy -y(x+y^3)dx=0$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

What is the solution of differential equation : $x(y^3-x)dy -y(x+y^3)dx=0$

My approach : 
$M = xy^3-x $ differentiating w.r.t. x we get  : M$_x = y^3 -2x$

$N = xy+y^4 $ differentiating w.r.t. y we get : $N_y = -x-4y^3$

Here $M_x \neq N_y$ therefore :

we have to use $\frac{M_x -N_y}{N} = \frac{5y^3+x}{y(x+y^3)}$

Please suggest whether it is correct or not, also suggest how to proceed further. . thanks

Answer (score 2):

You have two groups of terms with the same degree structure,
$$
0=[xy^3\,dy-y^4\,dx]-[x^2\,dy+xy\,dx]
$$
Both can be written as products of a monomial factor and the differential of a monomial
$$
=x^2y^3\,d(x^{-1}y)-x\,d(xy)=x^3y^2[(x^{-1}y)\,d(x^{-1}y)-(xy)^{-2}d(xy)]
$$
Now the second factor is fully integrable, and the extracted factor gives the integrating factor for the original expression as $(x^3y^2)^{-1}$. The solution curves are the level curves of
$$
C=\frac{y^2}{2x^2}+\frac1{xy}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $y^3=t, 3y^2dy=dt \implies x(t-x)dt/(3y^2) -y(x+t)dx=0$. Multiplying by $3y^2$,

$x(t-x)dt-3t(x+t)dx=0 \implies \frac{dt}{dx}=\frac{3t(1+t/x)}{x(t/x -1)}$.

$t/x = p, dt=xdp+pdx, \implies dt/dx = p + xdp/dx = \frac{3p(1+p)}{p-1}$. Which can now easily be solved using variable separable method.